# Prove that $\left \| A \right \| = \max_{\left \| x \right \|=1}\left \| Ax \right \|$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I've been given this problem:

> Prove that a subordinate matrix norm is a matrix norm, i.e., if $\left \| \cdot \right \|$ is a vector norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $$\left \| A \right \| = \max_{\left \| x \right \| = 1} \left \| Ax \right \|$$ is a matrix norm

I don't even understand the question, and a explanation on what the problem is asking me to do would be much appreciated. Specifically, what does $\max\limits_{\left \| x \right \|=1}\left \| Ax \right \|$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mapping $\|.\|$ from $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ to $\mathbb [0,\infty)$ is a norm if, for all matrices $A, B$ and all scalars $\alpha$:

- $\|A\|=0$ if and only if $A=0$
- $\|\alpha A\| = |\alpha|\|A\|$
- $\|A+B\|\leq \|A\|+\|B\|$
- $\|AB\|\leq \|A\|\|B\|$

So the task is asking of you to verify all those properties are true in your case.

Comment: but what the notation $max_{\left \| x \right \|=1}\left \| Ax \right \|$ mean?

Comment: @stenvikteam it means $$\sup_{\left \| x \right \|=1}\left \| Ax \right \|$$, do you know what $\sup$ means? (Btw the reason why we write $\max$ for $\sup$ here is because the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^n$ is *compact*, which would not be true in infinite-dimensional spaces)

Comment: @Vim Yes I do. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A Matrix Norm has to fullfill certain requirements. 
First, is has to be a norm, so it has to fullfill the three basic norm-Requirements.

1) Positivity

2) Linear wrt. to a constant

3) Triangular inequality

These are quite easy to show here.

Some Sources need a fourth thing, submultiplicativity. It means $\|A\| \cdot \|B\| \geq \|AB\|$ for all $A$, $B$. 
This, again, is easy to show, when you substitute your definition.

Comment: 2) is commonly referred to as (positive) homogeneity.